# How to detect WebView2 back and forward events?

Tags: javascript, winforms, webview2

I have tried using scripts like...

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function()
{
    alert(1);
});
```

and...

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function()
{
    alert(1);
});
```

... without luck.

Note that initialization is done properly, other scripts work, navigation is fine, and this is `WinForms`.

So, how to detect WebView2 back and forward events?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You can use [HistoryChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.historychanged?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44.&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Answer (score 1):

@RezaAghaei provided the answer above.

Subscribing to the `CoreWebView2.HistoryChanged` event does the trick.

[CoreWebView2.HistoryChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.historychanged?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&viewFallbackFrom=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44.)

Note that, naturally, this must be done after `CoreWebView2` has been initialized.

Subscribing to the `CoreWebView2.SourceChanged` event also works.

[CoreWebView2.SourceChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.sourcechanged?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44)